# Exporting Text with Curve Modifier Animation to Unity 3D

Tags: animation, modifiers, game-engine, bezier-curves, unity

I'm making a simple text animation following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bF3O4qbaMqs. Basically, it's making text running in circles by applying a circle/bezier curve modifier on it. So when I change the x value of the location of the text, it runs in circle, which works jsut fine in Blender. However, when I keyframe everything and move them into Unity, the curve modifier doesn't work and the text is just moving along the x-axis. How should I fix this in Blender, so I can have the text running in circle effect in Unity?

Comment: Please read https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: Blender modifiers will not work in a different program nor should you assume that the animations will either even though the basic keyframe do. You're could rig the object and bake the animation or shape key. But in this case though, just rotate the text GameObject in Unity around the circle center point. The right approach here is to model meshes in Blender and make objects move in Unity.